# Asynchronous update Data in Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm using ASP.NET and C# to design my webpage.

In the Webpage I have a GridView into which I'm populating Data from Database. The Data into the Database will come from another website.

What I need to Do is at a particular Intervals of time for ex (Every 1 Min) I need to check the Database for new Rows and If any new rows are present, then I need to show a notification to the Browser in my page that `(no) of new orders have come. Click here to load them.`. and when I click there the Page has to be refreshed and new rows are to be displayed.

How can I check the Database at every particular Interval??
can you help me?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you..

Answer (score 1):

you can fire ajax call at given interval and get the notification

```
 //first call 
yourAjaxFunctionHere();

 //later call done by settimeout function 
function yourAjaxFunctionHere() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html', 
    success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
  });
}
```

Tutorial for calling serverside code by jquery ajax

- [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html)
- [Jquery Ajax Calling functions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html)
- [Calling Cross Domain WCF service using Jquery/Javascript](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html)
- [Steps to Call WCF Service using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/steps-to-call-wcf-service-using-jquery.html)

Comment: can you explain ? I'm a rookie in Ajax calls

Comment: @KrishnaThota - hey check jquery ajax call on google you get some reday made article ...i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to get one of jquery timers: [Jquery Timer Plugins](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timers).
Then create serious Wcf or Asmx web service and ask it on every timer tick.
And then update your data making ajax request and update it putting GridView inside update panel.

Answer (score 0):

What about WCF callback?

[callbacks](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx)

Callbacks allow you to get the events directly from you server and you do not need to pull your server every X seconds.